# different before/after placeholders for \movie from multimedia package in beamer

Tags: beamer, multimedia

When one uses

```
\movie[]{ \includegraphics[]{} }{}
```

to set an image as the placeholder before a video begins in a slide, is there a way to set a different image that appears after the video plays?

I am using Ubuntu and have found that Okular is the only viewer that allows me to play video embedded by beamer.  It reverts to my original placeholder once the video completes.

I would really like it to hold the final view from the video if possible, because ultimately that is what I want anyway.  However, I have access to the final image since I am making the videos myself from a series of images so a solution that throws up an image right after the video plays is also fine.

Comment: On Ubuntu, [`pdfpc`](https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc) is a nice (2018) alternative to Okular, which gives the desired behavior for videos by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `open` option:

```
\movie[open]{ \includegraphics[]{} }{}
```

which, according to the [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf):

> Causes the player to stay open when the movie has finished.

The player will hold the last image of the video instead of returning to the first one. At least this works with Acrobat Reader on OSX.

However I haven't found a way of providing a custom image to be displayed at the end (besides of course appending it at the end of the video and using the `open` option).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could show the final image on the next overlay:

```
\only<1>{\movie[]{ \includegraphics[]{} }{}}
\only<2>{\includegraphics[]{your final image}}
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround if you want to display a custom final image (not the last view of the video). I think you should use it in combination with the 'open' option (otherwise it would return to the first image), but in any case you still have to manually tell the PDF viewer to go to the next overlay (by hitting space for example).

Comment: @pmk For a known duration of the video one could automatically do the slide transition.